# Shaking Windows application form

Tags: .net

i am learning windows forms applications in c# .net and trying to develop small games.I am not much experienced.So i need some help.Actually i am making a jackpot game in windows forms application and i want my form to shake or you can say vibrate when i click the play button.I don't know what you call it but I have done everything else and its complete.I just want to add this vibration to get good looks and fun.I've searched everywhere but found no solution.Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in your click event of the button :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                this.Left += 10;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
                this.Left -= 10;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
            }
        }
```

But i suggest don't use Windows Forms for gaming purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't work"?? there is a button that has a click event, button placed in a Form, you can test it and see this is working fine.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I run it under .Net version 4.5.1 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, it Works, just test it!

Comment: Nope it won't. You'll not be able to see the shaky effect. Am pretty sure.

Comment: No F**king way! It does work! I am sorry, everything I know about winforms programming tells me this should not work, but it does... I have deleted my previous comments.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ok you can say it, but in the real word it works.

Comment: Aero does this.  Don't try it on XP.

Comment: @HansPassant can you write up a more detailed explanation on my [follow-up question to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919845/why-does-my-form-not-lock-up). I would really like to know what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanx for help.But this slows up everthing else on the form for example numbers generating randomly.their speed decreases.

Comment: @SalmanJaved You can put the other codes into another Thread.

Comment: There's another thing.suppose i want to pause everything in the form or you can say the whole game.So what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything within your form inside a panel, set the panel's position from (0,0) to (-10, 0) and to (10, 0) (feel free to change those values) repeatedly when the button is pressed.