# Why does my form NOT lock up?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

While reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919376/80274) from another question I was 100% sure that the following code would lock up the UI and not cause any movement.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        this.Left += 10;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
        this.Left -= 10;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
    }
}
```

I and several others in the comments said it would not work but the OP insisted that it did and we should try. I ended up making a new Winforms project, adding a button, then putting the above code in the event handler for click and the form did indeed shake.

How is the form moving when the message pump is being blocked by this method, OnPaint should not be able to be called on the form nor any of its child controls, how is this working?

Comment: A form can move even without firing `Paint`.  It's still a bad idea.

Comment: @SLaks I am not saying at all that it is a good idea, I just want to know what the heck is going on that does let this work.

Comment: Something somewhere likely has `DoEvents` or some moral equivalent.

Comment: I believe that windows stores a "screenshot" of your window, and still allows moves to happen even if the message pump doesn't respond.  Eventually, the window may gray with windows showing a message that the app isn't responding.

Comment: Moving a form does not necessarily need a repaint. Maybe the DWM can simply show the old image at the new location.

Comment: That is why I asked this question, I thought of the same "maybes" and "Somewhere something's" as these previous comments, I just don't know the answer for sure. I asked this question so I could get a more detailed explanation of exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aero does this.  Windows don't render straight to the video frame buffer anymore, they render to memory.  Think "bitmap".  The DWM process then composites these bitmaps and blits them to the buffer.  This solves a number of window painting artifacts, the most infamous one was probably the "trail" you'd leave behind when moving one window across another.  Whatever process owned the bottom window had to catch up and repaint the revealed pixels.  That takes time and the unpainted pixels where visible.  Also allows for other special effects, like the live thumbnails you can see when you hover over a taskbar button, simply a copy of that bitmap shrunk to fit.  And Aero Peek, just a projection of that bitmap.  And glass in Vista and Win7.  And the special "screen" where Store apps are displayed in Win8.  And the visible marks you see when you touch the screen.

And affects this code as well, the window position is now simply a different location where the bitmap is composited.  The original bitmap is still intact and doesn't require repainting.

Don't try this on XP or with Aero turned off.

Comment: When you say `And affects this as well` I think you're missing a word, but I don't know what word that is.

Comment: This was my first thought, too, but I have distinct memories of running nearly identical code on Windows 2000 and XP. There were no obvious problems: no ghosting, no tearing, etc. I'm sure the application becomes unresponsive, but that's not really an issue. No one would ever try clicking on the form while it's shaking back and forth. With or without Aero, though, the window manager does paint it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible because of [Coroutines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164086.aspx) and  [Fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682661(VS.85).aspx).

Although a thread is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by the operating system scheduler, coroutines can exist within an application that share a single thread. This means that one routine can stop in its tracks while another executes, and then resume at the point where it left off, all within the same thread.

Evidently there is far more happening under the covers than we would have imagined when we set those seemingly innocuous properties `this.Left` and `this.Right`.

And we can see this happening, if we add a little logging to the code example from the question. Also—since I've removed the `Thread.Sleep(75)` calls in my example below, and added a longer sleep at an earlier point—we can see that it's not those sleeps that bring about the yield to the other function, but the calls to `this.Left` and `this.Right` (which, moreover, still shake the form without the sleep):

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
      if (_logWndProc)
          listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("WndProc on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

      base.WndProc(ref m);
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      listBox1.Items.Clear();
      _logWndProc = true;
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("After sleep on thread {0} (see any WndProc logs before this line?!!!)", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Right {0} on thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
          this.Left += 10;
          listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Left {0} on thread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
          this.Left -= 10;
      }

      _logWndProc = false;
  }

  private bool _logWndProc = false;
```

The log:

[image]